# Index into powershell Import-Csv row like an array

Tags: powershell, csv

I am importing data from various csv files, usually with 4 or 5 fields.

e.g. one might look like:

```
id, name, surname, age

1,tom,smith,32

2,fred,bloggs,50
```

I have managed to grab the header row titles into and array that looks like:

```
id, name, surname, age
```

the first data row looks like:

```
@{ID=1; name=tom; surname=smith; age=32}
```

say I assign it to `$myRow`
what I want to be able to do is access the ID, name etc field in `$myRow` by index, 0, 1, 2 etc, not by the property name.

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You could just load the file using `Get-Content` and then split on `,` to get an array of the values

Comment: ok i'll try that thanks.  If you feel an urge to post an example Id be grateful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this, but it may be slow for large sets of rows and/or properties:

```
$users = 
import-csv myusers.csv |
foreach {
 $i=0
 foreach ($property in $_.psobject.properties.name)
   {
    $_ | Add-Member -MemberType AliasProperty -Name $i -Value $property -passthru
    $i++
   }
 }
```

That just adds an Alias property for each property name in the object

Comment: thanks, wonder if you could access directly like $_.psobject.properties.name[0]

Comment: No, that's just going to get you the name of the first property in the list of property names.  To actually use that to access the property value of the object, you have to do it like: $_."$($_.psobject.properties.name[0])"

Comment: I found that using  $_.psobject.properties.value[0]  gave me what I wanted so thanks for the answer.  I'll mark this as the one I used.

Comment: Good answer for showing how to use Alias functionality.

Answer (score 1):

When I wanted to do something similar, I went about it differently.
I used Import-Csv to get the contents into a table.  Then I stepped through the table, row by row, and used an inner loop to retrieve the field values, one by one into variables with the same name as the column name.

This created a context where I could apply the values to variables embedded in some kind of template.  Here is an edited version of the code.

```
foreach ($item in $list) {
   $item | Get-Member -membertype properties | foreach {
      Set-variable -name $_.name -value $item.$($_.name)
      }
   Invoke-expression($template)  >> Outputfile.txt
   }
```

I'm writing the expanded templates to an output file, but you get the idea.  This end up working more or less the way mail merge applies a mailing list to a form letter.

I wouldn't use this approach for more than a few hundred rows and a dozen columns.  It gets slow.

Explanation:

> The inner loop needs more explanation.  `$list` is a table that contains
> the imported image of a csv file.  `$item` is one row from this table.
> `Get-Member` gets each field (called a property) from that row.  Each
> field has a name and a value.  `$_.name` delivers the name of the
> current field.  `$item.($_.name)` delivers the value.  `Set-Variable`
> creates a variable.  It's very inefficient to create the same
> variables over and over again for each row in the table, but I don't
> care.

This snippet was clipped from a larger snippet that imports a list and a template, produces an expansion of the template for each item in the list, and outputs the series of expansions into a text file.  I didn't include the whole snippet because it's too far afield from the question that was asked.

Comment: With my limited understanding of powershell so far, I don't really follow this code.
this syntax confuses me: `$item.$($_.name)`

and what is `Invoke-Expresison` and where did `$template` appear from?

Thanks for responding.

Comment: My understanding of Powershell is very limited as well.  I've got a lot of earlier technology under my belt, so my learning curve may be different.  I'm going to edit the answer to provide an explanation.

Comment: I have changed the way I go about this over the last five years.  I no longer use Invoke-Expression, but instead use ExpandString.  $template in the above example comes from code that is outside the snippet.  The entire tool is perhaps easier to decode than a snippet.

Comment: If you are interested in the tool I built for processing multiple CSV files,  I have posted it [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/273466/generate-sql-scripts-in-powershell).  The code posted there is not easy to read, and I apologize for that.  I'm using % as shorthand for "foreach" and $_ for "the current object" in both the outer pipeline and two inner pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually index your array with `($MyRow[1]).age` in order to get the age of the first row.